# How to integrate a loop in my code

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, joptionpane

I am new to Java.  My program first gets inputs from the user about their car, and then it shows the result. 
I need to integrate my "Rövarspråk" in to the code, but I am not really sure how. 
If the user owns a "Saab" or a "Volvo" the "rövarspråk" loop should change the user's "string name". 
If something is unclear, just tell me and I'll try to explain better.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lookSaab;

    String consonantsx;
    String input;
    String slang;
    String add;
    // String
    int length;
    // int
    Scanner skriv;
    // Scanner

    String reg;
    String year;
    String brand;
    String name;
    String car;
    String when;
    String small;
    String medium;
    String big;
    // String 
    int mod;
    int randomNumber;
    int quota;
    int denominator;
    // int







    reg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange registreringsnummer"); // Input plate number of your car
    year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange årsmodell"); // Input model year of the car
    mod = Integer.parseInt(year); 
    brand = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange bilmärke"); //Input car brand
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange ägare "
                                           + "(för - och efternamn)"); //Input owner of the car first name + last name
    car = brand + reg;
    Date date = new Date();
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
    when = sdf.format(date);
    denominator = 1500;
    randomNumber = 1500 + (int)(Math.random() * ((40000 - 1500) + 1));
    quota = randomNumber / denominator;

    small = "Liten service"; 
    medium = "Medium service";
    big = "Stor service";
    if (randomNumber <= 8000){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, small, "Typ av service", 1);
    } else if ( randomNumber <= 20000){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, medium, "Typ av service", 1);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, big, "Typ av service", 1);
    }

    String resultat = "Bil: " + car + "\n" 
                      + "Årsmodell: " + mod + "\n"  
                      + "Ägare: " + name + "\n"  
                      + "Mästarställning: " + randomNumber + "\n"  
                      + "Inlämnad: " + when + "\n"  
                      + "Klar om: " + quota + " dagar";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultat, "Resulat", 1);

    lookSaab = "Saab";

    if (brand.equals(lookSaab)){

    }

  /* Rövarspråket */



    consonantsx = "bBcCdDeEfFgGhHjJkKlLmMnNpPqQrRsStTvVwWxXzZ"; //Saves all consonants to string
char consonants[] = consonantsx.toCharArray();  //String to charr

System.out.println("Mata in en mening");
skriv = new Scanner(System.in);
input = skriv.nextLine();   //Saves the input
length = input.length();    //Length inc. space
char array[] = input.toCharArray(); // Input to a char array

slang = "";
    System.out.println("På rövarspråk:"); 
for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x<20; x++){
            if(array[i] == consonants[x])
            {
                add = array[i]+"o"+array[i];
                slang = slang + add;
                break;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(slang);
}
}
```

Comment: You do realize that 99% of people on this site have no idea what "Rövarspråk" is? You need to explain yourself better, and in a more "international" fashion.

Comment: e or E is a vocal, not a consonant. Please add comments to the code what the words mean in english.

Comment: I could explain "rövarspråket" but i don't think it is relevant to know what it is. The code should explain pretty good what i want to do/what the program does.
But anyhow info about "rövarspråket" kan be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6varspr%C3%A5ket

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein I have edited the eE, i have added some English comments to maybe make it easier to understand

Comment: So the people in your country speak a crazy language (sometimes :p) and you want to translate "normal" words into crazy. OK - so putting the Rövarsprak code in its own method would be a good point to start. Then you check when it is necessary to run this method and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so as mentioned a good start would be to put your RoverSpraket translator into its own method:

```
public String rovarSpraket(String normalString) {

    final String consonantsx = "bBcCdDeEfFgGhHjJkKlLmMnNpPqQrRsStTvVwWxXzZ"; 
    char consonants[] = consonantsx.toCharArray(); // String to charr

    int length = normalString.length(); // Length inc. space
    char array[] = normalString.toCharArray(); // Input to a char array

    String slang = "";
    System.out.println("På rövarspråk:");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            if (array[i] == consonants[x]) {
                String add = array[i] + "o" + array[i];
                slang = slang + add;
                break;
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
    return slang;
}
```

This method takes a "normal" String as input and returns the Rövarspråk version of it.

Given that it can be used anywhere you want now, like:

```
 /i named my class "Goran" ;)
    Goran goran = new Goran(); //instatiate a class object

    String hello = "hello world";

    System.out.println(goran.rovarSpraket(hello)); //use class object method "roverSpraket"
```

This will print as the following on the console:

På rövarspråk:
hoheoelollolloldod

Only thing left to do is use this in the remaining code. I guess what you want is that:

```
if (brand.equals("Saab") || brand.equals("Volvo")){
    name = rovarSpraket(name); //translate if brand is Saab or Volvo
}
```

And a working example for calling the method (one way to do it)

```
    public class Goran {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String brand;
        String name;

        //i named my class "Goran" ;)
        Goran goran = new Goran(); //instatiate a class object

        String hello = "hello world";

        System.out.println(goran.rovarSpraket(hello)); //use class object method "roverSpraket"

        brand = "Saab";
        name = "henry";

        if (brand.equals("Saab") || brand.equals("Volvo")){
            name = goran.rovarSpraket(name); //translate if brand is Saab or Volvo
        }

        System.out.println("new name is " + name);

    }

    public String rovarSpraket(String normalString) {

        final String consonantsx = "bBcCdDeEfFgGhHjJkKlLmMnNpPqQrRsStTvVwWxXzZ"; 
        char consonants[] = consonantsx.toCharArray(); // String to charr

        int length = normalString.length(); // Length inc. space
        char array[] = normalString.toCharArray(); // Input to a char array

        String slang = "";
        System.out.println("På rövarspråk:");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                if (array[i] == consonants[x]) {
                    String add = array[i] + "o" + array[i];
                    slang = slang + add;
                    break;
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
        return slang;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have never created different methods so I am not really sure how to do things
But now that i have created method "RoverSpraket", i am getting "non-static variable reg cannot be referenced from a static context" in min main method. Should i change something in my main method?

Comment: You can use the method ether in a static context or you use an instantiation of the class to call the method, i will add an example.

Comment: That example helped a lot, i had never created a method but that kind of made me understand how to integrate it with my code. Lets see if i'll make it :D

Comment: BTW, the output from your example was:
På rövarspråk:
hohlollolloldod
På rövarspråk:
new name is hoh

Comment: From the second example, yes. ;) - so do you accept this answer? xD

Comment: Well the output is wrong, hohlollolloldod and hoh is wrong answer. I tried with my first code that i uploaded and for some reason on names i get weird output but with words i get the right output
henry should be: hohenonrory

Comment: Hm the question was about integrating 'my "Rövarspråk"' into the code. ^^ How about opening another question about the "Rövarspråk" implementation and i help u there? =)

Comment: Sure, i have created a new question